# PHP CodeIgniter - how to get good result array when relational table (there are same column name in different table)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to make pretty query result like doctrine, and other ORM

for example with relational table article and article_category.

i want to get query result like this :

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array 
      (
          [id] => 1
          [title] => I am article title
          [slug] => i-am-article-title
          [category] => Array
                (
                     [id] => 1
                     [name] => Category Name
                     [slug] => category-name
                )
      )

    [1] => Array 
      (
          [id] => 2
          [title] => How to coding
          [slug] => how-to-coding
          [category] => Array
                (
                     [id] => 4
                     [name] => Tutorial Area
                     [slug] => tutorial-area
                )
      )

)
```

i know this is basic, but i am want to know for create that result in very simple way.

thanks for all advice

UPDATED.

for to get that result, I am change using eloquent laravel framework.. . :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't get this information in this way directly from your database if you are using a [Relational Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) like MySQL or PostgreSQL

You can get the effect you wish in two queries and insert the subquery array to your result array, or you can have a different table for your categories and do a JOIN with SQL.

As a note, other database systems return just what you asked, consider switching to MongoDB (a No-SQL solution) it returns an object just like you wished